# Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires '1' type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, namespaces

I am trying to create a program that will create a vector, generate 100 random numbers (0 - 99) and then ask for user input whether they want the numbers sorted from High to Low or Low to High.

This is the code I have so far just trying to get the vector working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Generic.List; //this is where the error comes.
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    class List<T>
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> vectorList = new List<int>();
            vectorList.Capacity(100);
            int i = 100;
            for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x++)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                i = rand.Next(0, 100);
                vectorList.Add(i);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Except I have no idea how to fix this issue, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you redeclaring `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`?

Comment: Your seem to have some confusion about the different elements of a C# program. I've tried to address some of these in my answer below; however, I would suggest that you take some time to read about the different constructs in the C# language so that you can use them effectively and appropriately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a side issue (BoltClock has it right), but change this:

```
List<int> vectorList = new List<int>();
vectorList.Capacity(100);
```

To this:

```
List<int> vectorList = new List<int>(100);
```

Also, remove the `<T>` from your class name.

Comment: Happens to be the source of the two errors OP lists under my answer. Those errors would explain why he had the `using` directive in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Remove that `using` line; `List` is a class, not a namespace so you don't have to "use" it.

Your `Main()` method ought to belong in its own class too; C# does not allow redefining an existing class to add a `Main()` method.

Also, [Joel Coehoorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797870/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-arg/4797906#4797906) will solve the problem you're having that I believe made you put that `using` line there in the first place, and [LBushkin's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797870/using-the-generic-type-system-collections-generic-listt-requires-1-type-arg/4797944#4797944) is worth heeding.

Comment: When I remove the line it gives me two more errors.

'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'Capacity' and no extension method 'Capacity' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and an error that reads just like that except Add is in place of Capacity.

Comment: @Cistoran: Joel Coehoorn has the solution in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

**There are a number of things you're doing here that aren't a good idea, and are directly responsible for some of the errors you're going to get.**

First, in C#, the `using` directive is intended to identify an entire namespace that you will depend on - and all of the types exposed in that namespace. The line

```
using System.Collections.Generic.List
```

doesn't refer to a namespace, but to a type (`List<T>`) - and is not appropriate.

Next, you are trying to create a generic class `List<T>` as the main class of your program ... and in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace no less. Well, this will conflict with the existing .NET `List<T>` class - so you will get errors from that as well.

What you really want to do here is create a namespace that is associated with (or describes) the program you are writing. Don't try to re-use the existing .NET framework namepsaces for that purpose. And don't name your class `List<T>`.

Finally, your class is not really a generic class ... the type parameter `T` is not used for any purpose in the program code. And your class is not an implementation of a list ... it's a ListProcessor (or something along those lines). You should be careful when naming classes or interfaces in a program so that they have a strong relationship to what they are named. It's also a good idea (when possible) to avoid creating names that collide with those already used by common classes in the .NET framework - as that can cause ambiguity and confusion in your code.

Comment: +1 Great advice! All I really said was that redeclaring existing namespaces/classes is illegal...

Comment: Yeah, I was changing some stuff around to reflect stuff that I was reading on MSDN, which I now realize has nothing to do with my issue. This is advice is sound though so it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

remove:

```
using System.Collections.Generic.List;
```

List is contained in the Generic namespace which you are already "using".

Answer (score 1):

You only need to import the namespace. So remove the offending line.

Other than that, you have declared your program class to be generic `List<T>`. You don't need that, your entry point should just be in a normal static class.